# How I can increase the qt version in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, qt

I need to update the latest qt version supported by the Ubuntu 22.04, the default version is  5.15.3. Please help me out to increase the qt version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a newer release of Ubuntu. Older releases = Older software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)